# Como criar um filtro de arquivo ao arrastar em C#

Tags: c#, listview, drag-n-drop, filter

Estou implementando a função de Arrastar arquivos para preencher uma Listbox com o caminho dos arquivos.

Ela funciona muito bem, mas eu gostaria de colocar um "filtro" tornando possível apenas txt serem importados.

caso não seja txt deveria surgir um MessageBox de erro ao usuário.

Segue o Código

```
private void listBoxArquivosSelecionados_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Link;
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    private void listBoxArquivosSelecionados_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] arquivos = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as string[];
        if (arquivos != null)
            listBoxArquivosSelecionados.Items.AddRange(arquivos);
        CarregarStatus();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deixa pra la, descobri como faz, só varrer o vetor e se a string conter o padrão ".txt" vai ser adicionada na lista, se não, apresentar mensagem de erro, segue código.

```
private void listBoxArquivosSelecionados_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] arquivos = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as string[];
        if (arquivos != null && arquivos.Any())
        {
            foreach(string arquivo in arquivos)
            {
                if (arquivo.Contains(".txt"))
                    listBoxArquivosSelecionados.Items.Add(arquivo);
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Carregue apenas arquivos de Texto (.txt)", "Atenção");
            }
        }
    }
```